# When to use which search technique in Sharepoint development?

Tags: sharepoint, search

When I have to use KeywordSearchQuery, when should I use FullTextSearchQuery and when should I use Query in developing the search part in Visual Studio for a Sharepoint site?

I want to search information from Contact list. If any keyword is put in the search box, I wan related information in our own specified format. Which technique should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the situation. In your case, since you are searching a Contacts list, I would recommend using a regular CAML and SPQuery.

In general:

- One list, use a CAML query
- Many lists, use search